# How to pipe the res file to google cloud storage stream to save file on gs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform

```
import {Storage} from "@google-cloud/storage";
this.post(
  "/webhook",
  async (req, res) => {
    const storage = new Storage({/** google credential filename */ });
    const clientBucket = storage.bucket(/** bucket name */);

      // Create a reference to a file object
      const fileName = `${moment().format("YYYYMMDDHHmmss")}.tar.gz`;
      const file = clientBucket.file(fileName);
      req.pipe(file.createWriteStream());
      req.on("end", () => {
        // have to update in db that file has been uploaded
      });
   })
```

Running this code on my local node server which is not uploading the file on gs storage. This is the post-call in this. I am receiving the stream data in req. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. If I write the req.pipe() in a local folder, it creates a file. Please note I am not getting any errors in the terminal.

Post call request headers :
[image]

Comment: I am running the node server on my local where I have defined this post route, and my other server, which is written in python, calls this route and sends the file in a request, which I have to upload on google storage.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write JSON file to `/tmp` directory using `fs.createWriteStream` and then pipe file from `/tmp` to Storage using Storage API.

Comment: Can I not do it without storing and directly pipe to google storage API?

Comment: @HimanshuTeotia, no, because you receive a string from your request, and you need to transform it to file.